# Postgresql - unique constraint allowing only ONE null

Tags: sql, postgresql

On PostgreSQL, I have a table with the columns `name`, `surname` and `_deleted`.

`name` and `surname` cannot be duplicated, so I had a unique constraint on them and everything was good.

after that, I added the `_deleted` for soft deletes. If I add `(name, surname)` and then I soft delete it, I cannot add anymore `(name, surname)`.

I thought that the solution was adding unique to `(name, surname, _deleted)` but it does not work, because _deleted is a DateTime that is null when it is not deleted, hence NULL can be multiple.

How can I add a proper constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_name_surname
    on t(name, surname)
    where _deleted is not null;
```

You cannot (easily) do this with a unique constraint, but this is functionally equivalent to a constraint.

Comment: Does it change the update performance? I do not know how the constraints are checked, but adding an index would change the update performance and occupies size on disk. However it works, than you!

Comment: @EuberDeveloper . . . The performance is pretty much the same.  Unique constraints are implemented using unique indexes.  The filtering on the index has little impact on performance.

Comment: Using a unique constraint is as adding an index but without having the improved searches? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can make a conditional unique index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX names ON (name,lastname) WHERE (_deleted is NOT null);
```